# Writing to text file in GAE

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt

Has anyone figured out a way to write to text file on the server-side using [Google App Engine (GAE)](https://developers.google.com/appengine/). I understand the limitation of not being able to use FileWriter, but I was wondering if there was a work around. Thanks!

Comment: You cannot create files on the GAE web server. Consider storing your data in datastore or blobstore (it's possible to create blobs programmatically in latest update).

Comment: Documentation on creating blobs programmatically:http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/overview.html#Writing_Files_to_the_Blobstore

Comment: Thanks guys! I think I'm gonna try out the blobstore.

Answer (score 2):

Not only can you not use `FileWriter`, you can not write to files at all, since you do not have access to the filesystem from within the GAE. It's impossible by design.

As a "work-around" (which I hesistate designating as such since this is a technically valid solution), you can emulate a filesystem using the GAE datastore using GAEVFS: http://code.google.com/p/gaevfs/

Comment: You do have access to the filesystem - you just can't write to it.

Comment: Well no, you don't have direct programmatic access to the FS; the best you can do is request servlet resources via the Java Servlet Standard. Unless there's a feature I'm not aware of?

Comment: Yes, you can read files from the FS directly, just as you would on any other platform.

Answer (score 0):

Try the blob store. Now, you can write to the blob store like you write files to the file system.

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/overview#Writing_Files_to_the_Blobstore